# Open Notepad with C# application in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, notepad, system.diagnostics

I wrote this program to open Notepad with C# application in Windows Command Prompt but it can´t

What is the problem?

```
namespace msdos
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite) { sw.WriteLine("notepad.exe"); }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why in ms-dos? not directly?

Comment: You should put `p.WaitForExit();` at the very end, not before writing to the stream.

Answer (score 4):

Try to launch any commands like that :

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "notepad.exe");
```

you can replace notepad.exe by any command.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C notepad.exe";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Or simpler:

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText = "/C notepad.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```